How to impute OPEN_CLS_STS based on values in DT_CLS
I'm trying to impute the OPEN_CLS_STS based on the values in DT_CLS.
IF DT_CLS has a date populated then OPEN_CLS_STS should have a value 'C'. Otherwise OPEN_CLS_STS should have a value 'O'.
I tried using the function below but it doesn't seem to work:
def fill_based_on_conditions(project): 
    if project['DT_CLS'].isnull():
        return project['OPEN_CLS_STS'] == 'O'
    else:
        return project['OPEN_CLS_STS'] == 'C'

Any suggestions?
enter image description here
The desired output is if DT_CLS is populated with a date, then I want to populate OPEN_CLS_STS with 'C'. Otherwise I want to populate OPEN_CLS_STS with 'O'.

What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Please make a reproducible pandas example including example input, desired output, and actual output. See also [mre]. Then you should be able to ask a more specific (i.e. more useful) question about the problem you're experiencing. See [ask] for tips on that.

Hi, I just updated the post.

You need to define a condition and use numpy.where/numpy.select or pandas' where.

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (for print(df)) or table formatting (from print(df.to_markdown()). As well, that's not a reproducible example since all the DT_CLS values are NaN.

An example with Pandas:
df = pd.DataFrame({"DT_CLS": ["date1", "date2", np.nan, np.nan, "date3"]})
df["OPEN_CLS_STS"] = df["DT_CLS"].map(lambda x: "C" if x is not np.nan else "O")
display(df)


